# Stuck in MYSQL procedure using 'order by variable'

Tags: mysql, procedure

this is paramater

```
IN `_user_id` VARCHAR(50), 
IN `_page` INT, 
IN `_sort_type` VARCHAR(50), 
IN `_order_type` VARCHAR(50)
```

and this is procedure

```
BEGIN

if _page < 0 then
    set _page = 0;
end if;

if _sort_type='idx' then
    set _sort_type = '__idx';
end if;


PREPARE STMT FROM
"
select idx, trash, publisher_user_id as user_id
from n_board 
where publisher_user_id = ?
order by ? desc LIMIT ?,?";
SET @publisher_user_id = _user_id;
SET @sort_type = _sort_type;
SET @order_type = _order_type;
SET @START = _page*4;
SET @END = 4;
EXECUTE STMT USING @publisher_user_id, @sort_type, @START, @END;
END
```

This is part of my code. I made this code due to the limit variable.
I heard that MYSQL 5.5 supports code like this 'limit variable, variable'. Is it correct? I'm using 5.0.77.

I hope to use order by and sort type like this:

```
'order by ? ? LIMIT ?,?'
```

but this is does not work.

`select no from n_board where id = ? order by ? ? LIMIT ?,?";` -> syntax error

```
select no from n_board where id = ? order by ? desc LIMIT ?,?";
```

-> I get results, but 'order by desc' is not having any effect.

What can i do?

Comment: Hello, please try to formulate your question in a more concise manner, I've edited your post to the best of my understanding but I couldn't tell what is your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using @LIMIT as a variable, it could be upset because its a reserved word.

Comment: and has it made a difference?

Comment: Your statement with two ? after the order by, you will need to include an ASC or a DESC tag, you cant leave it as a number for the limit which is the next variable you put in.

Comment: i call like this CALL `getMyBoards`('abc', '0', 'idx', 'desc')

Comment: How can you hope that "select no from n_board where id = _id" could work?

Comment: OK but getMyBoards('abc', '0', 'idx', 'desc') doesnt allow for the limit variables. Can you please post the full code in your "getMyBoards" procedure?

Comment: thank you BugFinder and nick rulez! I solved this with 'http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21786' just now